# Magento change "Home" menu item in multi-site

Tags: php, magento

I need to change the "Home" navigation menu item to "Main" in my Magento Pro v1.10 site.  We are using a multisite setup, and this needs to change in all of the sites.  It seems like this should be simple, but I have done a lot of Internet searching can't seem to find this anywhere

Please help.

Comment: Note that I need to change just the title in the menu, not the page that it links to.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe this is so difficult!
Here's an example: http://www.doggeekz.com/
I need to change the "Home" in the upper left navigation menu to "Main".  The home page is CMS but I find no place that "Home" is available to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the navigation file from: `/YOUR_SITE/app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/template`
There find the navigation file (often named top.phtml) and change the following code:

```
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('megamenu/menu/home')): ?>
    <li class="level0 home level-top <?php if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == (Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig('web/default/cms_home_page'))) {echo " active";}?> m-dropdown ">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>" class="level-top"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></span></a> <!--change to <span>Main</span> -->
    </li>
<?php endif;?>`
```